Finite sets in Coq
I am a beginner and trying to figure out how to work with finite sets and maps in Coq. I want to define an inductive type X with a single constructor that takes as an argument a finite set of elements of type X, for example:
Inductive X : Set :=
| constr : FinSet X -> X.
I am unsure which data structure to use for finite sets here. I looked into the std++ library but do not understand the data structure provided there: Set_ seems to require two types, A and C, and I do not know why the second type C is needed. Ideally I want a finite set constructor that takes one type as an argument (the type of elements), which is countable but not necessarily ordered. I am a beginner so I have a hard time reading Coq library files; can someone maybe post a code snippet? Thank you.

In stdpp the type you want to use is gset, defined in gmap.v.

@JoJoModding Thank you, I tried it but it does not work: Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
In environment:
X : Type
?EqDecision0 : "base.RelDecision eq"
?H : "countable.Countable X"
It seems the issue is that by using gset inside an inductive definition, Coq does not automatically derive countability.

Ah, yes, it does not. That is unfortunate, but I don't think this can be fixed.

This is not a research-level question in theoretical computer science, so it does not belong here. But it does belong on https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com, so perhaps you should ask it there instead.

I usually use
Definition finite X : Prop := exists l, forall x : X, In x l.
Definition fin {X} (P : X -> Prop) := exists l, forall x, P x <-> In x l.

These ones have quite good properties.
